# Where does unity-webapps gets installed?

Tags: unity, 13.04

When reddit.com asked if I want to install reddit unity webapp, on clicking ok it got installed directly wihtout asking for my password. Does that mean it's installed in user's directory? If no, then why it didn't ask for my password?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is just a desktop file. I find the desktop file of gmail in the `~/.local/share/applications`. The name is GMailmailgooglecom.desktop.

Comment: But when you click Gmail webapp icon you run `/usr/share/unity-webapps/userscripts/unity-webapps-gmail/GMail.user.js`